# Animate appendChild div height javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition, appendchild

I have written this code that shows an error message until the email is written correctly. I would like to make the message display smoothly and push the elements it has up and down also smoothly (smooth height from 0 to default height) with javascript or css or both, but I don't know how. I don't know if I'm explaining myself well...

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
  } else {
    if (!document.querySelector('.error')) {
      const errorMessage = document.createElement('div');
      errorMessage.setAttribute('class', 'error');
      errorMessage.innerHTML = `<div class="showerror"><p>error</p></div>`;
      email.appendChild(errorMessage);
    } else if (inputEmail.value === "") {
      email.removeChild(document.querySelector('.error'));
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS transitions like

```
    * {
-webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
-o-transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
transition: all ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
```

This example is applied to all the elements. If you only need one it's better to write the specific selector instea of '*'.

You can modify the effect using different delays and animation styles, read more on w3schools :
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: I imagine it has to be done with transitions, and I know how transitions works but I don't know how to apply it in the specific case that I show. I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: In this case I would actually suggest  to add the error div to html and set its height to 0, then in your JS function instead of creating the element, fill it with the content and expand the height.

Comment: Hi Marie, I rewrite the code with the suggested modifications and it works, but now the error content remains. How could i delete it?

Comment: You can target your error div with javascript and toggle the contenet with innerHTML function

Answer (score 0):

This is the new code with the suggested modifications, but now the error content remains. How could i delete it?

```js
const email = document.querySelector('#email');

eventListeners();

function eventListeners() {
  email.addEventListener('keyup', validateEmail);
}

function validateEmail() {

  const email = document.querySelector('.email'),
    error = document.querySelector('.error'),
    inputEmail = document.querySelector('#email'),
    formatEmail = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  if (inputEmail.value.match(formatEmail)) {
    error.classList.remove("show-error")
  } else {
    if (inputEmail.value !== "") {
      error.innerHTML = `<p>error</p>`;
      error.classList.add("show-error")
    } else {
      error.classList.remove("show-error")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.error {
  width: 200px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #d5d5d5;
  text-align: center;
}

.show-error {
  max-height: 100px;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="name">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
</div>
<div class="email">
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div class="error"></div>
</div>
<div class="password">
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
</div>
```